# How to plot SymPy's built-in functions using sympy.plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

Hey I am pretty new to SymPy. I am trying to use SymPy's built-in plotting to plot some functions. My codes are as follows:

```
from sympy import Symbol, sin, Function, pi,exp
from sympy.plotting import plot

t = Symbol('t')
source = t**2
plot(source,(t,0,1))
```

This works perfectly. However, notice that I have also imported functions such as `sin` and `exp` above. However, I am finding anything involving these functions, SymPy will not plot. For example,

```
source1 = exp(t)
source2= sin(t)
plot(source1,(t,0,1))
plot(source2,(t,0,1))
```

Neither of these will work. The error I received is as follows, using the case with `sin` as an example:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sympy/plotting/experimental_lambdify.py in __call__(self, args, kwargs)
    194             #The result can be sympy.Float. Hence wrap it with complex type.
--> 195             result = complex(self.lambda_func(args))
    196             if abs(result.imag) > 1e-7 * abs(result):

TypeError: complex() first argument must be a string or a number, not 'FunctionClass'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-85c4f08c25e4> in <module>
      1 f0 = 15
      2 source = sin(t)
----> 3 plot(exp(t),(t,0,1))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py in plot(*args, **kwargs)
   1556     plots = Plot(*series, **kwargs)
   1557     if show:
-> 1558         plots.show()
   1559     return plots
   1560 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py in show(self)
    189             self._backend.close()
    190         self._backend = self.backend(self)
--> 191         self._backend.show()
    192 
    193     def save(self, path):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py in show(self)
   1246 
   1247     def show(self):
-> 1248         self.process_series()
   1249         #TODO after fixing https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/1255
   1250         # you can uncomment the next line and remove the pyplot.show() call

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py in process_series(self)
   1243             if isinstance(self.parent, PlotGrid):
   1244                 parent = self.parent.args[i]
-> 1245             self._process_series(series, ax, parent)
   1246 
   1247     def show(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py in _process_series(self, series, ax, parent)
   1072             # Create the collections
   1073             if s.is_2Dline:
-> 1074                 collection = self.LineCollection(s.get_segments())
   1075                 ax.add_collection(collection)
   1076             elif s.is_contour:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py in get_segments(self)
    661                     list_segments.append([p, q])
    662 
--> 663             f_start = f(self.start)
    664             f_end = f(self.end)
    665             sample(np.array([self.start, f_start]),

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sympy/plotting/experimental_lambdify.py in __call__(self, args, kwargs)
    234                         ' problematic. We are trying a failback method'
    235                         ' that may still work. Please report this as a bug.')
--> 236                 if abs(result.imag) > 1e-7 * abs(result):
    237                     return None
    238                 else:

AttributeError: type object 'exp' has no attribute 'imag'
```

This might be something trivial, but as a beginner I am having quite a hard time figuring these out. Really appreciate your help!!

Comment: When I try your examples, they work quite similar to the first example, without errors.   Maybe it helps to upgrade to the latest versions? (Python 3.6 is from 4 years ago)

Comment: @JohanC. I think you are correct! Just tried it with Python 3.7 on my local machine, and it works!